# How can I extract events log from Android application?

Tags: android, process, event-log, logcat, android-logcat

I was able to extract main logs from Android application by using the following code:

```
String[] LOGCAT_CMD = new String[] {
    "logcat",
    "-d",
    "MyApplication:E",
    "*:S"};
    Process logcatProc = null;

    try {
        logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LOGCAT_CMD);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream ireader = logcatProc.getInputStream();
        int temp;
        while ( (temp = ireader.read()) != -1 ){
            while ( temp !=  64 ){
                strOutput.append( (char) temp);
                temp = ireader.read();
            }
            strOutput.append(lineSeparator);
            line = strOutput.toString();
            writeLine(line);
            strOutput = new StringBuilder();
        }
```

However, when I try to use the same method to extract event logs, it does not work. I have no idea what the problem is, but when I change LOGCAT_CMD to the following and run the application, ireader.read() returns -1 right away and finishes.

```
String[] LOGCAT_CMD = new String[] {
            "logcat",
            "-b",
            "events",
            "-d",
            "[1]:I",
            "*:S"
            };
```

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this code](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/). In particular look at collectAndSendLog() in [SendLogActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java).

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. When I set LOGCAT_CMD to "logcat -b main -d" it works fine. However, When I try "logcat -b events -d" or "logcat -b radio -d", InputStream ireader returns -1 right away and finishes.